# Type of field dependent on type of other field

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Is it possible to create a class like

```
from typing import Union, Literal

class Foo:
    bar: Union[str, int]
    qux: Literal["str", "int"]
```

such that, if `qux` is `Literal["str"]`, then `bar` is of type `str`, and if `qux` is `Literal["int"]`, then `bar` is of type `int`? Is it possible to annotate that?

I'm aware of `typing.overload`, but I don't think it's relevant for this example

Comment: What you describe are dependent types. The general answer is "No", though for specific cases one can emulate this (e.g. by overloading a constructor). Would that match your need?

Comment: probably - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependent types are not generally supported by Python's `typing` system. However, it is possible to emulate some specific cases.

For a low number of dependent types, one can enumerate the cases. This requires making the individual types generic:

```py
from typing import Union, Literal, Generic, TypeVar

Bar = TypeVar("Bar", str, int)
Qux = TypeVar("Qux", Literal["str"], Literal["int"])


class GenericFoo(Generic[Bar, Qux]):
    bar: Bar
    qux: Qux

    # not always needed – used to infer types from instantiation
    def __init__(self, bar: Bar, qux: Qux): pass
```

It is then possible to define the dependency either

- as a `Union` of the cases:

  ```py
  Foo = Union[GenericFoo[str, Literal["str"]], GenericFoo[int, Literal["int"]]]

  f: Foo
  f = GenericFoo("one", "str")
  f = GenericFoo(2, "int")
  f = GenericFoo("three", "int")
  ```
- by `overload`ing the instantiation:

  ```py
  class GenericFoo(Generic[Bar, Qux]):
      bar: Bar
      qux: Qux

      @overload
      def __init__(self, bar: str, qux: Literal["str"]):
          pass

      @overload
      def __init__(self, bar: int, qux: Literal["int"]):
          pass

      def __init__(self, bar: Bar, qux: Qux):  # type: ignore
          pass
  ```